# Endophytic Xylariaceae: diversity and taxonomy inferred from rDNA sequence analyses

Tags: microbiology, mycology

"Thailand is considered as one of the areas containing a high percentage of unknown taxa of *Xylariaceae* (Rogers 2000).  In Thailand, several studies on endophytic fungi have been documented, namely, from several bamboos (Luyong et al. 2000), banana (*Musa acuminata*) (Photita et al. 2001), monkeypod/rain tree (*Samanea saman*) (Chareprasert et al. 2006), and several xylariaceous endophytes were also reported from those plants."

*Review quoted from Izumi okane, Prasert Srikitikulchai, Kyoko Toyama, Thomas Laessoe etc. Full Paper; Study of endophytic Xylariaceae in Thailand: diversity and taxonomy inferred from rDNA sequence analyses with saprobes forming fruit bodies in the field.*

Have any of you known the similar cases (the high percentage of Xylariaceae) in the USA, France, or UK, proved by reference(s)?

Comment: Are you looking for areas that high a high percentage of Xylariaceae as compared with total fungi species richness? Or for areas that have a high percentage of unknown taxa of Xylariaceae compared with total Xylariaceae taxa?

Comment: @Oreotrephes: The high percentage of Xylariaceae in the USA, France, or UK, proved by reference(s), thanks.